# Wicket + WAS: calling url causes a redirect to a wrong URL causing 404

Tags: websphere, wicket, wicket-1.6, websphere-liberty

Using **Websphere Application Server + Wicket 1.6** 
I am having some issues with my mounted URLs.

When I invoke an url akin to: `localhost:9080/danesCooking/pies/meat` I see the following in the Chrome network tab:

```
localhost:9080/danesCooking/pies/meat status code 302
localhost:9080/danesCooking/meat?2 status code 404
```

So it seems the /pies/ portion gets lost. This behaviour does not occur when I deploy my application to `Tomcat\JBoss\`... .

Possibly relevant, pies itself is not a mounted page.

I've already looked through some of the wicket issues\forums and it seems most issues seem to be either resolved\conflicting answers\have to do with relative urls (**fixed in 1.5.x**).

Has anyone experienced this issue and still recalls how to resolve this?

Used **WAS **Versions: 7 and 8.5**** liberty.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is actually outlined here;
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3258

My resolution to the issue in Wicket 6.9.1 was;

```
public class MyApplication extends WebApplication {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage() {
        return MyHomePage.class;
    }

    /* *********************************************** */
    // Resolve Websphere Relative URL "sendRedirect" Bug

    @Override
    protected WebResponse newWebResponse(WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        return new FixedServletWebResponse((ServletWebRequest) webRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    /**
     * Websphere incorrectly handles relative redirect pages when "HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(url)" is called.
     * 
     * This small fix ensures that Websphere is only ever provided with absolute URLs so that this issue never occurs.
     */
    private static class FixedServletWebResponse extends ServletWebResponse {
        private final ServletWebRequest webRequest;

        protected FixedServletWebResponse(ServletWebRequest webRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
            super(webRequest, httpServletResponse);
            this.webRequest = webRequest;
        }

        @Override
        public String encodeRedirectURL(CharSequence url) {
            Url relativeUrl = Url.parse(url);
            return new UrlRenderer(webRequest).renderFullUrl(relativeUrl);
        }
    }

    /* *********************************************** */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve that using anonymous class as described in the [Configuring and Deploying Open Source with WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248194.html?Open) chapter 5.2.4. (Tested with WLP 8.5.5.3 and Wicket 6.8.0)

Override the following method in your `WebApplication` class:

```
    @Override
    protected WebResponse newWebResponse(final WebRequest webRequest, final
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
    {
        return new ServletWebResponse((ServletWebRequest) webRequest,
                httpServletResponse)
        {
            @Override
            public String encodeRedirectURL(final CharSequence relativeURL)
            {
                return new UrlRenderer(webRequest).renderFullUrl(Url.parse(relativeURL));
            }
        };
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Other solution, instead of code change, is to set the following property in the webcontainer (works in 8.5.5.3):

```
<webContainer com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.redirectwithpathinfo="true" />
```